# How to match color of statusBar and topAppBar even when scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to match the color of the status bar and the top app bar colors to be the same, similarly for the navigation bar and bottom app bar, just like in Google Keep notes when scrolling a specific note. I am using Jetpack Compose.

I tried using `windowInsets` but it is a static color that does not change on scroll.

**Dark Theme**

[image]

**Light Theme**

[image]